# IntelliJ Idea with Gradle: Best Practices

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I am developing a Java application using IntelliJ Idea 14.1.4.
If it would have been solely Java application, I would have known exactly how to structure the project in Idea:
A single Java project, containing several modules: One for each part of the application (JAR).There will be at most 4-5 JARs.

The dependencies between the modules are also known: **Protocol** does not depend on anything, everything else depends on **Infrastructure**, and so on.
Next, I would like to use Gradle scripting for managing the project. So my question is what is the best practice to structure the code in Idea?

Should I create a single Gradle Project and a Gradle module for each of the JARs?

Should I create a single Java project (or maybe empty project) and Gradle modules for each of the JARs?

Should I create a single Gradle project and each of the modules will be a Gradle's sub-project? Maybe it will be better to have an empty project and several Gradle modules because not all of the JARs are closely coupled?

Since I have never used Gradle before, I would appreciate any guidance for the best practices when combining both Gradle and Idea.

Thanks,

Guy

Comment: One project with several dependent JARs would be the way I'd go.  That's what I do with Maven.  Keep it simple until you have evidence that there's a better way.

Comment: Your project structure should not depend on IDE.
But this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/gradle.html) should help you to understand how to work with Gradle in IDEA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as possible, I would keep the code in one source repository. On the root, I would have an "empty" project not outputting anything. All your jar projects would be sub-projects (in Gradle terms). You include them via the `settings.xml` file located in the root project.

Each sub-project has its own `build.gradle` file. In those files, you can easily define the dependencies between your sub-projects, e.g.:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':subProject3')
}
```

For convenience, I often create a special `export` task to put all artefacts in one `export/` folder on the root level so that you don't need to go through all those sub-folders to get your stuff.

```
task export(type: Copy) {
    from project(':subProject1').jar
    from project(':subProject2').jar
    from project(':subProject3').war
    into 'export/'
}
```

IntelliJ Ultimate 14 works fine with this approach. You can simply hit `Make` to compile everything. You might also want to configure your project settings to run `gradle jar` or `gradle export` during a make if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This really guides me towards building the project correctly.